# Poweriso doesn't accept parameter -add why?

Tags: command-line, iso-image

I use CMD to run a command to make a .iso file.
Based on https://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/command-line-argus.htm this should be a correct command

```
set piso="%programfiles%\PowerIso\piso.exe"
cd C:\temp2 
for /d "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o "d:\%a.iso" -add "d:\temp2"
```

But I get this error

```
Bad parameter: -add
```

Why ? What is wrong?

Comment: According to the instructions "-add <local dir/file name> <dir in image file>: Add local file or directory to image file." So -add  takes 2 parameters, you have only given 1

Comment: Your tags have nothing to do with your problem.  Before you try stuff through a batch file, ensure your command works directly.  I am guessing that you didn't even *try* the command line directly as indicated in your tags.  After getting a command line to work directly, use the `echo` command in your batch to see that the command is being spit out as your might want it to.  Then remove the echo and try again.. if all else fails, THEN pass stuff to SuperUser.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I solved, is possible to delete this question ?

Comment: Either you yourself or @Silbee should post an answer and you should accept it.

Comment: @JackRock the idea of the site is to create a place where questions are asked and solutions are presented. There might be merrit to your question for others in the future, who would then hopefuly stumble upon this page and see they made a similar error and find the solution here. So if you found out what the problem was, its completely ok to create the answer yourself.

Comment: @Silbee ok, I write now. It was missing the `/` at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
set piso="%programfiles%\PowerIso\piso.exe"

cd C:\temp2

for /f "usebackq" %a in (`dir /b /ad`) do %piso% create -o  "C:\%a.iso" -add "C:\temp2" /
```